# Postgres alleviate update lock contention while maintaining nonce

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have a balance table which is being updated each time a client request is registered. The balance   account will be updated, and a corresponding transaction record inserted. A transaction record will keep a nonce field which increments sequentially. Essentially a transaction will look like below, where , and  are pull out of the previous `UPDATE` result.

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE client_balances SET nonce = nonce + 1, balance_amount = balance_amount - 100 WHERE client_id = 100 RETURNING *;

INSERT INTO transaction_records (date, client_id, nonce, balance_changed, balance_amount) VALUES (TIMESTAMPTZ '2023-01-01-XXX', 100, <nonce>, -100, <balance_amount> RETURNING *;

COMMIT;
```

When concurrent requests reaches ~200/seconds to a single client balance account, the `UPDATE` clause will reach its performance limit, and will take around 400ms on average to complete on a moderately performant Linux box. This is due to lock contention from the ~80 concurrent connections to the database which all tries to update the same balance record.

To alleviate the problem, I decided to divide the client_balance record into 32 bins for each client, so concurrent updates can be distributed evenly and randomly into those bins. What this means in code is:

```
BEGIN;

UPDATE client_balances SET nonce = nonce + 1, balance_amount = balance_amount - 100 WHERE client_id = 100 AND bin = <rand_int_from (0,31)> RETURNING *;

SELECT SUM (nonce) AS nonce_aggr, SUM (balance_amount_aggr) AS balance_amount FROM client_balances WHERE client_id = 100 returning *;

INSERT INTO transaction_records (date, client_id, nonce, balance_changed, balance_amount) VALUES (TIMESTAMPTZ '2023-01-01-XXX', 100, <nonce_aggr>, -100, <balance_amount_aggr> RETURNING *;

COMMIT;
```

Now each time a client balance is used, it is aggregated from the 32 bins. <nonce_aggr> and <balnce_amount_aggr> are also from the aggr in the postgres transation. The balance seems to be correct, however, nonce in the records will not be: instead of being sequential like 1, 2, 3, 4..., it will now become 1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6..., although the total count is correct. This is totally understandable because the `UPDATE` clause only locks one of the 32 bins.

To correct the nonce, is it advisable to take 32 locks on all the 32 bins? Or is there a better way of doing this?

I will need the nonce field in the records to be in sync with the balance record. So a balance change like below

```
   nonce.     change.      balance
   1001.                            20000.    (initial)
   1002.       +10              20010
   1003.       +30.            20030
```

Should generate two transaction records 1002 and 1003, as such. Postgres's builtin sequence will not be in sync under such

Comment: The better way is not to do it.  Why are you doing this at all? You could use a sequence to get a nonce.

Comment: I edited the content to describe the requirement for the nonce to be in sync with the balance record. Nevermind issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The lock on `client_balances` will be held until the end of the transaction. So to improve concurrency as much as possible:

1. update `client_balances` as the *last* statement in the transaction, so that the row will be locked as briefly as possible
2. use a prepared statement for the `UPDATE`, so that the execution time will be as fast as possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The planning phase is fast enough so prepared statement will not help too much. Also client_balances cannot be hte last statement in the transaction - I will need its updated nonce to be populated in the records. Anyways the performance issue is solved using a separate aggregator step instead. Thanks anyway.